# Codeigniter update_batch() with included update of the where key

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I want to update multiple rows in the database with codeigniters `update_batch()` function.
But the **field specified in the where** should also be changed.

The following code should make it clear:

```
$set = array(
  array(
    'token'           => '65787131678754',
    'device'          => 'none',
    'new_token_value' => ''
  ),
  array(
    'token'           => '75798451315464',
    'device'          => 'none',
    'new_token_value' => ''
  )
);

$this->db->update_batch(TBL_NAME, $set, 'token');
```

Tokens specified in `token` should be updated with `device` to `'none'` and the `token` itself should be set to empty string `''`.

Is this possible with `update_batch()` function?

---

In sql I would write something like

```
UPDATE TBL_NAME
SET token='', device='none'
WHERE token='65787131678754'
```

for one update but this is not practicable for multiple, so I want to use the `update_batch()` function.

Comment: did you try it already? what is the error?

Comment: @tomexsans I did not try it because I don't know how to define the "new_token_value". But I can not add 2 times `token` in the same array one with the actual token value and another with the new value.

Comment: then the update batch is not the problem, the problem is how you would update the data as you want it to happen.

Comment: So should I do it with pure sql and a loop for each token? But this won't be a good solution I think. Do you have a better idea how to update multiple entrys?

Comment: Take a look at codeigniter transactions.

Comment: I looked at the codeingiter transactions and they do not seem to fit for my problem, because every sql query in the transaction I run is automatically executed. But to update many entries this should be done by one batch query and not by many single ones.  
  
To fix the issue I wrote a function like `update_batch()` which generates the same sql code but with the ability to update also the identifier. I will post the code here tomorrow.

Comment: May be it's same problem with
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42993337/7760664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a helper function mostly identical to the codeigniter `batch_update()` function.
But with the ability to update the index itself. The new value is defined by `index_update_key`.

```
function update_batch($db, $table = '', $set = NULL, $index = NULL, $index_update_key = '') {
if ($table === '' || is_null($set) || is_null($index) || !is_array($set)) {
    return FALSE;
}

$sql = 'UPDATE ' . $db->protect_identifiers($table) . ' SET ';

$ids = $when = array();
$cases = '';

//generate the WHEN statements from the set array
foreach ($set as $key => $val) {
    $ids[] = $val[$index];

    foreach (array_keys($val) as $field) {
        if ($field != $index && $field != $index_update_key) {
            $when[$field][] = 'WHEN ' . $db->protect_identifiers($index) 
                            . ' = ' . $db->escape($val[$index]) . ' THEN ' . $db->escape($val[$field]);
        } elseif ($field == $index) {
            //if index should also be updated use the new value specified by index_update_key
            $when[$field][] = 'WHEN ' . $db->protect_identifiers($index) 
                            . ' = ' . $db->escape($val[$index]) . ' THEN ' . $db->escape($val[$index_update_key]);
        }
    }
}

//generate the case statements with the keys and values from the when array
foreach ($when as $k => $v) {
    $cases .= "\n" . $db->protect_identifiers($k) . ' = CASE ' . "\n";
    foreach ($v as $row) {
        $cases .= $row . "\n";
    }

    $cases .= 'ELSE ' . $k . ' END, ';
 }

 $sql .= substr($cases, 0, -2) . "\n"; //remove the comma of the last case
 $sql .= ' WHERE ' . $index . ' IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';

 return $db->query($sql);
}
```

Now I can do the following

```
$set = array(
  array(
    'token'           => '657871316787544',
    'device'          => 'none',
    'new_token_value' => ''
  ),
  array(
    'token'           => '757984513154644',
    'device'          => 'none',
    'new_token_value' => ''
  )
);

update_batch($this->db, 'table_name', $set, 'token', 'new_token_value');
```

and the sql output is

```
UPDATE `b2c` SET 
`token` = CASE 
WHEN `token` = '657871316787544' THEN ''
WHEN `token` = '757984513154644' THEN ''
ELSE token END, 
`device` = CASE 
WHEN `token` = '657871316787544' THEN 'none'
WHEN `token` = '757984513154644' THEN 'none'
ELSE device END
WHERE token IN (657871316787544,757984513154644)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('option1', $option1);<br/>
$this->db->update_batch('table_name', $data, 'option2');
```